# How to draw mirrored x-axis(inverted) bar chart in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart which uses brush and zoom. I want the graph to show buy price and sell price in a day. So far I was able to add buy price to the chart like this https://jsfiddle.net/070yqew2/

I found [this](http://vis.stanford.edu/jheer/d3/pyramid/shift.html) and [this](http://population-pyramids.github.io/#/Toronto%252C%2520ON%2520(CD)/Montr%25C3%25A9al%252C%2520QC%2520(CD)) as interesting graphs that are relevant to the design. I do not find any idea to implement this, any graph that show mirrored representation with brush and zoom should help a lot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">

body {
  font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}


.axis {
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: #888;
  font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
}

.axis > path {
  stroke: #888;
}


</style>

<body>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


     function randomData(samples) {
            var data = [],
                random = d3.randomNormal();

            for (i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
                data.push({
                    "Date" : new Date("May"+ (i+1)+", 2016 "),
                    "Buy" : Math.floor(Math.random()*100000),
                    "Sell" : Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)
                });
            }
            return data;
        }

    var data = randomData(30);

  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["Date"] });
  var yMax = Math.max(20, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["Buy"] }));


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 90, left: 50},
    margin2 = {top: 230, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;



var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

      x.domain([xMin, new Date()]);
      y.domain([0, yMax]);
      x2.domain(x.domain());
      y2.domain(y.domain());

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).tickSize(0),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  var bars = focus.append("g");
    bars.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
    bars.selectAll("bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('x',function(d) { return x(d["Date"]) })
        .attr('y',function(d) { return y(d["Buy"]) })
        .attr('width',7)
        .attr('height',(d=>height-y(d["Buy"])))
        .style("fill","03a63c")
        .style("opacity",0.8)


  focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(yAxis);

  // Summary Stats
  focus.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("bars (in the day)");


  svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + ((width + margin.right + margin.left)/2) + " ," +
                             (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Date");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

  // append scatter plot to brush chart area
   var bars = context.append("g");
       bars.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
       bars.selectAll("bar")
           .data(data)
           .enter().append("rect")
           .attr('class', 'barContext')
           .attr('x',function(d) { return x2(d["Date"]) })
           .attr('y',function(d) { return y2(d["Buy"]) })
           .attr('width',2)
           .attr('height',(d=>height2-y2(d["Buy"])))
           .style("fill","03a63c")
           .style("opacity",0.8)


  context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.move, x.range());
    function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.selectAll(".bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d["Buy"]); });
  focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  focus.selectAll(".bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d["Date"]); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d["Buy"]); });
  focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
};

</script>
```

I need something like this

[image: Buyer and Seller interface]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, I found the answer to the question. I used d3.stack() function which is really cool.
Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/zuueksc5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">

body {
  font-family: avenir next, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}


.axis {
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: #888;
  font: 10px avenir next, sans-serif;
}

.axis > path {
  stroke: #888;
}

#tooltip {
        background-color: rgba(187, 187, 187, 0.7);
        border-radius: 5px;
        height: 18px;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        }

</style>

<body>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>



    var data = [{"Date":"2015-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":554646.5,"Sell":-406301.3547},{"Date":"2015-02-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":565499.5,"Sell":-673692.5697},{"Date":"2015-03-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":421954.5,"Sell":-571685.4629},{"Date":"2015-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":466242.0,"Sell":-457477.7121},{"Date":"2015-05-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":350199.7,"Sell":-579682.8772},{"Date":"2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":391035.1,"Sell":-338816.6205},{"Date":"2015-07-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":437644.6,"Sell":-502329.557},{"Date":"2015-08-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":291978.9,"Sell":-504067.0329},{"Date":"2015-09-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":360913.8,"Sell":-489519.6652},{"Date":"2015-10-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":505799.1,"Sell":-723353.7089},{"Date":"2015-11-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":510691.0,"Sell":-374061.8139},{"Date":"2015-12-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":527757.1,"Sell":-597800.0116},{"Date":"2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":564799.1,"Sell":-451779.1593},{"Date":"2016-02-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":336533.7,"Sell":-522601.1707},{"Date":"2016-03-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":460684.6,"Sell":-643556.0079999999},{"Date":"2016-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":428388.1,"Sell":-349216.2376},{"Date":"2016-05-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":525459.5,"Sell":-597258.4075},{"Date":"2016-06-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":677659.1,"Sell":-513192.107},{"Date":"2016-07-02T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":365612.8,"Sell":-287845.8089},{"Date":"2016-07-03T00:00:00.000Z","Buy":358775.2,"Sell":-414573.209}]


    data.forEach(d => {
                  d["Date"] = new Date(d["Date"]);
    })
  var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d["Date"] });
  var yMax = Math.max(20, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["Buy"] }));


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 230, left: 50},
    margin2 = {top: 250, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 350 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["Buy", "Sell"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);    

   var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
     .attr('id', 'tooltip');

 var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height ,0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height2, 0]);

      x.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d) { return d["Date"]; }))
      y.domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
      x2.domain(x.domain());
      y2.domain(y.domain());

    function stackMin(serie) {
    return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
        }

    function stackMax(serie) {
    return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
        }

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).tickSize(0),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 50])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + (height+80)+ ")");

  var bars = focus.append("g");
    bars.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("height",height)
        .attr("width",width);
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);
  focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(yAxis);

 bars.selectAll("g")
      .data(series)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key) })
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr('class', 'bar')
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("width",10)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data["Date"])})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])})
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1])})

  //appending brush to context
   var bars = context.append("g");
       bars.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
       bars.selectAll("bar")
          .data(series)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d; })
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr('class', 'barContext')
            .attr("width",5)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x2(d.data["Date"])})
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y2(d[1])})
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y2(d[0]) - y2(d[1])})


  context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.move, x.range());
    function brushed() {
          if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
          var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();

          x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));

          focus.selectAll(".bar")

                    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data["Date"])})
                    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])})
          focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
          svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
              .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
              .translate(-s[0], 0));
        }


    function zoomed() {
      if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
      var t = d3.event.transform;
      x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
      focus.selectAll(".bar")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data["Date"])})
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])})
      focus.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
      context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
    }



</script>
```